# Chef node/client submits its own tag to chef server

Tags: tags, chef-infra

Is it possible that a chef client notifies chef server that its new tags/role ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes but we were literally talking about deprecating this feature today so maybe don't? `node.tag('foo')` will add that tag to the node. But again, don't do this.

Comment: Will there be other options available for a node to tag itself or manage it's own runlist?

Comment: Tags yes, run list no. Oddly I just published a thing today about why nodes shouldn't be able to change their run list: https://coderanger.net/chef-and-vault/ (applies to a lot of things outside of Vault too)

Comment: I understand the security concern behind having a node modify its run_list, but it removes the ability to uninstall services. For example, we may throw a jenkins agent onto a machine that's not using all of its resources for a short period of time and then uninstall it. When we remove jenkins, we can't just remove the role - we have to add a jenkins::uninstall type recipe. The uninstall recipe removes itself from the run_list. This solution would go away - are there plans for an alternative?

Comment: Removing something from the run list doesn't uninstall it today, you always need an explicit removal or uninstall recipe. That's just how Chef (or rather Promise Theory-base systems) works.

Comment: And leaving the `::uninstall` recipe in the run list is generally harmless, if you wrote your code to be idempotent and convergent it will jsut continue to ensure the service is uninstalled which should be a no-op after the first time hopefully. You can do a GC cleanup in a management script instead (or just don't bother).

Comment: That's makes sense. In the event we're adding it back we'd just modify the process of adding to the node to ensure the `::uninstall` recipe doesn't exist,and remove it if it does.

Comment: There's nothing more to discuss. I'm already reachable on the Chef IRC channel, 4 different Chef related Slack teams, and Twitter. Pick one of those, I'm not checking yet more chat systems :P